# Problems with parsing simple C source code using Bison

Tags: c++, c, parsing, grammar, bison

Here's the parser code I'm using

```
%{
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "c.ast.hpp"
#include <typeinfo>
#define YYDEBUG 1

using namespace std;

// stuff from flex that bison needs to know about:
extern "C" int yylex();
int yyparse(BlockOfFunctions *ast);
extern "C" FILE *yyin;
 
void yyerror(BlockOfFunctions *ast, const char *s);

#define TRACE printf("reduce at line %d\n", __LINE__);


%}
%token  IDENTIFIER I_CONSTANT F_CONSTANT STRING_LITERAL FUNC_NAME SIZEOF
%token  PTR_OP INC_OP DEC_OP LEFT_OP RIGHT_OP LE_OP GE_OP EQ_OP NE_OP
%token  AND_OP OR_OP MUL_ASSIGN DIV_ASSIGN MOD_ASSIGN ADD_ASSIGN
%token  SUB_ASSIGN LEFT_ASSIGN RIGHT_ASSIGN AND_ASSIGN
%token  XOR_ASSIGN OR_ASSIGN
%token  TYPEDEF_NAME ENUMERATION_CONSTANT

%token  TYPEDEF EXTERN STATIC AUTO REGISTER INLINE
%token  CONST RESTRICT VOLATILE
%token  BOOL CHAR SHORT INT LONG SIGNED UNSIGNED FLOAT DOUBLE VOID
%token  COMPLEX IMAGINARY 
%token  STRUCT UNION ENUM ELLIPSIS

%token  CASE DEFAULT IF ELSE SWITCH WHILE DO FOR GOTO CONTINUE BREAK RETURN

%token  ALIGNAS ALIGNOF ATOMIC GENERIC NORETURN STATIC_ASSERT THREAD_LOCAL

%start translation_unit
%parse-param {BlockOfFunctions *ast}

%union {
    string *str;
    TypeSpecifier typespec;
    FunctionDefinition *func;
    BlockOfFunctions *blockfunc;
    Declaration *decl;
    vector<Declaration> *decls;
    Signature *sig;
}

%type<typespec> type_specifier declaration_specifiers
%type<str> IDENTIFIER
%type<func> external_declaration function_definition
%type<blockfunc> translation_unit
%type<decl> parameter_declaration
%type<decls> parameter_list parameter_type_list
%type<sig> declarator direct_declarator
%%

declaration_specifiers
    : type_specifier { TRACE $$ = $1; }
    ;

type_specifier
    : VOID {
        cout << "creating void" << endl;
        $$ = TypeSpecifier::Void; }
    | INT { cout << "creating int" << endl; $$ = TypeSpecifier::Int; }
    ;

declarator
    : direct_declarator { $$ = $1; }
    ;

direct_declarator
    : IDENTIFIER {
        Signature sig;
        string name = *$1;
        sig.name = name;
        $$ = &sig;
        cout << "creating identifier " << sig.name << endl;
    }
    | direct_declarator '(' parameter_type_list ')' {
        cout << "with argument" << endl;
        
        cout << "got declarator " << *$1 << endl;
        cout << "creating declaration " << $3->at(0) << endl;
        $$ = $1;
    }
    | direct_declarator '(' ')' {
        $$ = $1;
        cout << "argument less function" << endl; 
    }
    ;

parameter_type_list
    : parameter_list {
        $$ = $1;
        cout << "creating parameter type list " << $$->at(0) << endl; 
    }
    ;

parameter_list
    : parameter_declaration {
        vector<Declaration> params;
        cout << "pushing back " << *$1 << endl;
        params.push_back(*$1);
        $$ = &params;
        cout << "creating parameter declaration " << $$->at(0) << endl;
    }
    ;

parameter_declaration
    : declaration_specifiers declarator {
        cout << "creating param declaration" << endl;
        Declaration decl;
        string name = $2->name;
        decl.type = $1;
        decl.name = name;
        $$ = &decl;
    }
    ;

translation_unit
    : external_declaration { ast->block.push_back(*$1); }
    | translation_unit external_declaration { ast->block.push_back(*$2); }
    ;

external_declaration
    : function_definition  { TRACE $$ = $1; }
    ;

function_definition
    : declaration_specifiers declarator '{' '}' {
        string name = $2->name;
        FunctionDefinition fn;
        fn.ret = $1;
        fn.name = name;
        $$ = &fn;
    }
    ;

%%
#include <stdio.h>

void yyerror(BlockOfFunctions *ast, const char *s)
{
    fflush(stdout);
    fprintf(stderr, "*** %s\n", s);
}
```

Then I try to parse the following source code using this

```
void empty(int a) { }
```

But I get the following output

```
bison -t -v -o c.tab.cpp -d c.y
flex -o c.lex.cpp -l c.l
g++ c.tab.cpp c.lex.cpp cc.cpp -lm -ll -lfl -o cc
./cc examples/test.c
creating void
reduce at line 63
creating identifier empty
creating int
reduce at line 63
creating identifier a
creating param declaration
pushing back declaration: int a

creating parameter declaration declaration: int a

creating parameter type list declaration: void 

with argument
got declarator signature: a

creating declaration declaration: void 

reduce at line 129
retv = 0
function: void a
```

It's incorrectly parsing the function name to be `a`, when it should be `empty`. I've narrowed down the error to the point a specific location: the `parameter_list` non-terminal is correctly getting parsed, but when it's moved up to `parameter_type_list`, it's changed into a completely different object. You can see that from the runtime printed information.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure that out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement (and other similar ones) are clear undefined behaviour:

```
$$ = &decl;
```

You're attempting to store a pointer to a local variable whose lifetime is about to end. When that dangling pointer's value is eventually used, it no longer refers to anything.

I strongly suggest you add `-Wall` to your g++ flags. I don't know if gcc will detect this error, particularly without optimisation flags, but there's no point not giving it a chance to warn you.

Without seeing your flex code, I can't tell whether you are also passing dangling pointers as semantic values of tokens, which is another common cause of mysteriously mutating semantic values. You might want to check that as well.

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't think of that. I'm not experienced with C++, can you tell me what would be the correct way of doing this? I mean returning pointers to objects in this specific case. I'll have to return to pointers to objects one way or another, but as I understand I'm doing it the wrong way.

Comment: I used the `new` operator, and used `delete`d the objects later whenever they weren't going to be used anymore. Fixed everything, Thank you so much!